# Id AutoIncrement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не знаю с чем это связано - странно работают приращивания Id в таблицах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это не главная проблема (в принципе это не мешает). Есть связанная таблица которая связана с Id этой таблице. SQL выдает ошибку когда пытаюсь вставить запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [WorkerId] [int] NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NULL,
    [PriorityId] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [CompletionDate] [date] NULL,
    [ManagerId] [int] NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TaskFile]    Script Date: 17.06.2018 17:53:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TaskId] [int] NULL,
    [FileId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TaskFile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_Project] FOREIGN KEY([ProjectId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_Project]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_User] FOREIGN KEY([ManagerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_User]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_Worker] FOREIGN KEY([WorkerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Worker] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_Worker]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_File] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[File] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_File]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_Task] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Task] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_Task]
GO
```

Comment: покажите структуру обеих таблиц и код FK

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis приложил

Comment: покажите содержимое [dbo].[File]

Comment: скорее всего, вот тут ошибка в логике:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_File] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[File] ([Id])
вместо TaskID должно быть FileID

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis И правда, не заметил. Спасибо большое. Оформите ваш комментарий как ответ. И кстати, не знаете причину такой работы Id в моих таблицах

Comment: сложно сказать. как вариант - при вставке строк была ошибка, но счетчик в таких ситуациях все равно увеличивается. или же из таблицы удалялись данные.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Сомневаюсь, что столько раз ошибка была. Возможно это из-за того, что я добавляю данные с помощью рефлексии. Ладно, спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: после того, как создадите корректные ограничения - попробуйте вставлять данные. если они будут вставляться без ошибок, то пробелов в identity быть не должно.

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis Понял

Comment: Пропуск 1000 значений автоинкремента обычно возникает после рестарта сервера: [SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Yaant и как этого избежать

Comment: C `IDENTITY` - никак. Да и зачем? А вообще, там же сказано: "If gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never committed."

Comment: @Yaant Понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вот тут ошибка в логике:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskFile] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TaskFile_File]
FOREIGN KEY([TaskId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[File] ([Id])
```

Вместо TaskID должно быть FileID